# How can I create Liferay web content structure's outside of Liferay configuration?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I'm very new to Liferay theme development and i'm trying to find the most optimal workflow for development.

So I've been experimenting with creating Web Content Templates and Web Content Structures within Liferay CMS configuration.

What I would ideally like to do is create my view "Web Content Structure" outside of Liferay configuration and instead have it as a view/template inside my theme files so that I can have my code peer reviewed and version controlled in Bitbucket.

Is this possible?

Alternatively is there a way to output the values of a given web content instance within my theme?

I'm building a theme for Liferay 7 by the way.

Thanks in advance
Richard

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste the structure when you create them form the LFR editors into your source code repository.

Also if you know how to define the JSON you can do it straight in the file. The free market templates are even easier to edit in file format. When you're done, you need to go and upload the artefacts to the portal via the editor/file upload option.

You can't stick it into the theme because that approach would not allow you to do updates.

You can search for a community plugin or write your own one that would do structure/template updates during deploy.